# spark-sql on google dataproc from sbt scala

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

Using Google Dataproc Spark cluster, my sbt built assembly jar can access Cassandra via SparkContext.

However, when I try to access via sqlContext I get spark sql classes not found on the remote cluster - though I believe the dataproc cluster is supposed to be provisioned for spark sql.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/UTF8String$
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLRow$$anonfun$fromJavaDriverRow$1.apply$mcVI$sp(CassandraSQLRow.scala:50)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala
```

my sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.0" % "provided",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.4.0"
)
```

Turning off "provided" on spark-sql puts me in jar duplicate merge hell.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you also need version `1.5.0` of the `spark-cassandra-connector` to ensure your classes are compatible. Here's the [commit which upgraded the cassandra connector to 1.5.0](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/commit/d12f8e041d0cd497db3f80e613ec1bafd5da734c), and you can see it removes the import of `org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String` and adds `import org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String` instead, changing the relevant lines in `CassandraSQLRow.scala`:

```
       data(i) = GettableData.get(row, i)
       data(i) match {
         case date: Date => data.update(i, new Timestamp(date.getTime))
-        case str: String => data.update(i, UTF8String(str))
+        case bigInt: BigInteger => data.update(i, new JBigDecimal(bigInt))
+        case str: String => data.update(i, UTF8String.fromString(str))
         case set: Set[_] => data.update(i, set.toSeq)
         case _ =>
       }
```

Though it appears there are only "milestone" artifact types rather than "release" types in [Maven central for the cassandra connector](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10), you should still be able to get the latest milestone connector [1.5.0-M2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.5.0-M2) to work with your code.

EDIT: Additional link to the [compatibility table from the Cassandra connector's GitHub README.md](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility)

Comment: thx a lot @dennis, that looks like the answer.  

trying it now but 1.5.0-M2 gives assembly deduplicate issues with `io.netty`.  i'll have to refresh my knowledge of sbt deps after all...   i'll post the results soon...